# Rails - How do I auto-increment month and year from an entered number?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my rails app, I have an input field for "number of years of experience". This is when I as an employer is creating/editing a profile for a employee. And the number of years of experience will show up in the employee profile. Now how do I go about auto increment the years of experience by month and year? I obviously wouldn't want to show the same years of experience as time passes.

Answer (score 2):

For your use case, a better approach would be to save the date for when the employee started working in a DateTime field, say "work_exp_start_date".

You can then calculate the years of experience for that employee as difference between current date and start date.

Comment: this solution would work if im showing experience just from the start of this company. Even the previous work experience should also be added. Looks like I need to make another column and add it somehow

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be create one column to store months_experience.  Convert years into months before saving.

Another column would be experience_update_at which would save when that field last updated.

Now display months by following calculation

```
total_months_experience = 
  months_experience + 
  (experience_update_at.year * 12 + experience_update_at.month) - (Time.zone.now.year * 12 + Time.zone.now.month)
```

use `total_months_experience` to calculate years and months

Comment: This will require 2 columns. The problem can be solved with just one.